# Auto redirect after vote

Tags: development, plugin, redirect

how to add auto redirect URL after voting ? its possible? here is the code

```
public function vote(){
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $params = $app->getParams();
    $vote=$params->get('vote');
    $db =JFactory::getDBO();
    $user=JFactory::getUser();
    $user_id=$user->id;
    $vid=JRequest::getVar('vid');
    $Itemid=JRequest::getVar('Itemid');
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    if($ip):
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__photo_contest_ip WHERE item_id='$vid' AND ip_address='$ip'";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $count=$db->loadResult();
    endif;

    if($user_id):
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__photo_contest_ip WHERE item_id='$vid' AND user_id='$user->id'";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $count1=$db->loadResult();
    endif;
    if($count || $count1):
    $msg = JText::_('COM_PHOTO_CONTEST_ITEM_VOTE_ALREADY');
    else:
        if($vote==2 && empty($count)):
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->update('#__photo_contest_photo');
            $query->set('votes=votes+1');
            $query->where('id='.$vid);    
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->query();
            $insert= "INSERT INTO #__photo_contest_ip(ip_address,item_id) values ('$ip','$vid')";
            $db->setQuery($insert);
            $db->query();

            if (!$db->query()) {
                        $this->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
                        return false;
             }
             $msg = JText::_('COM_PHOTO_CONTEST_ITEM_VOTE_SUCCESSFULLY');


          elseif($vote==1 && $user_id>0):
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->update('#__photo_contest_photo');
            $query->set('votes=votes+1');
            $query->where('id='.$vid);    
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->query();
            $insert= "INSERT INTO #__photo_contest_ip(ip_address,item_id,user_id) values ('$ip','$vid','$user_id')";
            $db->setQuery($insert);
            $db->query();

            if (!$db->query()) {
                        $this->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
                        return false;
             }
              $msg = JText::_('COM_PHOTO_CONTEST_ITEM_VOTE_SUCCESSFULLY');
          else:
              $msg = JText::_('COM_PHOTO_CONTEST_ITEM_VOTE_LOGIN');
          endif;


     endif;
     $link=JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_photo_contest&view=photocontest&id='.$vid.'&Itemid='.$Itemid, false);
     $this->setRedirect($link, $msg);


}
```

Comment: what vote thing is this?

Comment: Hi, picture voting plugin

Comment: after vote,need to redirect to article/url
http://www.probeauty.cz/soutezopromenu/photocontest/39

Comment: Is this something you have developed or what? what is the article/url ?

Comment: article url is souteze, http://www.probeauty.cz/souteze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$app->enqueueMessage($msg, 'Success');
$app->redirect($link);
```

That will queue up your system message and then redirect the application to your link.